# My ralink5370 wifi adapter disconnecting randomly

Tags: wireless, drivers, adapter

I have bought a ralink5370 wifi adapter . it disconnects randomly .
in fact, I understand it from `lsusb` when it's connected or not .
I'm running ubuntu 14.04.2 minimal .
this is my dmesg output after connecting it :

```
[ 5564.693869] usb 3-6: new high-speed USB device number 98 using xhci_hcd
[ 5564.728096] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=5370
[ 5564.728106] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5564.728111] usb 3-6: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[ 5564.728116] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: Ralink
[ 5564.728120] usb 3-6: SerialNumber: 1.0
[ 5564.841932] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 98 using xhci_hcd
[ 5564.868994] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ebfa442c
[ 5564.869003] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ebfa4400
[ 5564.869009] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ebfa4458
[ 5564.869013] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ebfa4484
[ 5564.869018] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ebfa44b0
[ 5564.869022] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ebfa44dc
[ 5564.869026] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ebfa4508
[ 5564.869386] ieee80211 phy88: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5390, rev 0502 detected
[ 5564.880195] ieee80211 phy88: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5370 detected
[ 5564.880582] ieee80211 phy88: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[ 5564.913832] ieee80211 phy88: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[ 5564.913844] systemd-udevd[15166]: renamed network interface wlan0 to wlan1
[ 5564.913863] ieee80211 phy88: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29
[ 5565.068340] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
[ 5567.698146] usb 3-6: USB disconnect, device number 98
[ 5568.120607] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 99 using xhci_hcd
[ 5568.120752] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5568.324546] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5568.528370] usb 3-6: device not accepting address 99, error -71
[ 5568.640382] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 100 using xhci_hcd
[ 5568.640525] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5568.844406] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5569.048173] usb 3-6: device not accepting address 100, error -71
[ 5569.160199] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 101 using xhci_hcd
[ 5569.160351] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5569.364230] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5569.568039] usb 3-6: device not accepting address 101, error -71
[ 5569.680011] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 102 using xhci_hcd
[ 5569.680156] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5569.884019] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5570.087833] usb 3-6: device not accepting address 102, error -71
[ 5570.087910] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 6
[ 5575.373939] usb 3-5: new full-speed USB device number 103 using xhci_hcd
[ 5575.374052] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5575.578001] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5575.781728] usb 3-5: device not accepting address 103, error -71
[ 5575.893751] usb 3-5: new full-speed USB device number 104 using xhci_hcd
[ 5575.893863] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5576.097787] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5576.301606] usb 3-5: device not accepting address 104, error -71
[ 5576.413609] usb 3-5: new full-speed USB device number 105 using xhci_hcd
[ 5576.413754] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5576.617597] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5576.821391] usb 3-5: device not accepting address 105, error -71
[ 5576.933380] usb 3-5: new full-speed USB device number 106 using xhci_hcd
[ 5576.933529] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5577.137411] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5577.341203] usb 3-5: device not accepting address 106, error -71
[ 5577.341301] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[ 5582.503394] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 107 using xhci_hcd
[ 5582.503542] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5582.707400] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5582.911185] usb 3-6: device not accepting address 107, error -71
[ 5583.023156] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 108 using xhci_hcd
[ 5583.023293] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5583.227231] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5583.430997] usb 3-6: device not accepting address 108, error -71
[ 5583.543024] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 109 using xhci_hcd
[ 5583.543172] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5583.747020] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5583.950806] usb 3-6: device not accepting address 109, error -71
[ 5584.062830] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 110 using xhci_hcd
[ 5584.062977] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5584.266802] usb 3-6: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5584.470611] usb 3-6: device not accepting address 110, error -71
[ 5584.470681] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 6
[ 5599.313295] usb 3-5: new full-speed USB device number 111 using xhci_hcd
[ 5599.313439] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5599.517317] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5599.721106] usb 3-5: device not accepting address 111, error -71
[ 5599.833114] usb 3-5: new full-speed USB device number 112 using xhci_hcd
[ 5599.833257] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5600.037121] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5600.240943] usb 3-5: device not accepting address 112, error -71
[ 5600.352943] usb 3-5: new full-speed USB device number 113 using xhci_hcd
[ 5600.353091] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5600.556943] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5600.760724] usb 3-5: device not accepting address 113, error -71
[ 5600.872722] usb 3-5: new full-speed USB device number 114 using xhci_hcd
[ 5600.872873] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5601.076722] usb 3-5: Device not responding to set address.
[ 5601.280540] usb 3-5: device not accepting address 114, error -71
[ 5601.280621] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a "bandaid" but it could be a fix for you. install ndis-wrapper and download the Windows driver for your USB WiFi adapter and use ndis wrapper to import the driver into Ubuntu.

You can find ndis wrapper and it's gui in the Ubuntu Software Center
let me know if this helps.

Comment: http://cdn-cw.mediatek.com/Downloads/windows/IS_Setup_ICS_050615_1.5.39.126.exe
I have found an .exe driver for it but ndis-wrapper requires .ini file .
I have a Windows XP on virtualbox, any chance ?

Comment: how about this: http://www.ralinktech.com/support.php?s=2

Comment: how about this: http://www.ralinktech.com/support.php?s=2 now open a terminal and type cd Downloads/files_name    then sudo su   make     make install      modprobe rt5370sta   then reboot and hopefully things will be working. please post

Comment: your link is broken because Mediatek have bought Ralinktech .
I sold it and buy another ralink5370 ! and it is working fine :
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=3.13.0-55-generic firmware=0.29 ip=192.168.1.* link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn